# An application of Implicit Function Theorem in differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f$ be a continuous function from $\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R$. By a *solution of the differential equation*
$$f(x,y,\dot{y}) = 0$$
We mean a function $y\colon U \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ where $u$ is an open interval in $R$ that satisfies $f(x,y(x),\dot{y}(x))= 0$.

Let $f\colon \Bbb R^3 \to\Bbb R$ be a smooth function. Let $f(0,0,0) = 0$. Give a sufficiency condition under which the differential equation $f(x,y,\dot{y})$ admits a solution satisfying the initial condition $y(0) = 0$ in a neighbourhood of $0$.

I think I must use the Implicit Function Theorem but not sure how?

Comment: To give a sufficiency condition for $f(x,y,\dot{y}$ to admit a soln with the given initial conditions.

Comment: Think of what do you need in order to rewrite an equation $f(x,y,z)=0$ as $z=g(x,y)$.

Comment: I was thinking of the same thing. But nothing comes to mind.

Comment: In order to use the implicit function theorem, you have to know what it says. Do you know the statement of the implicit function theorem, its hypotheses and conclusion?

Comment: If $f(a,b)=0$ and $df$ is invertible at $(a,b)$ then there is a unique $g$ such that $f(g(y),y) =0$ for every $y$ in a neighbourhood of $b$.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put together two facts:

- *Implicit function theorem.* If  $\partial f/\partial z$ is nonzero at $(0,0,0)$, then for some neighborhood $U $ of $(0,0,0)$ the set $U\cap \{(x,y,z) : f(x,y,z)=0\}$ can be written as $U\cap \{(x,y,g(x,y)\}$ with a smooth $g$.
- *Existence-Uniqueness  theorem*. The ODE problem $\dot y =g(x,y)$, $y(0)=0$, has a unique solution provided that $g$ is smooth in a neighborhood of $(0,0)$.

Indeed, the smoothness of $g$ implies the continuity and Lipschitz continuity conditions in the existence-uniqueness theorem.